# How to create a payload from a anonymus function

Tags: php, serialization, eval, transmission

I wanted to send a function using some sort of transmission to another script.

For this I needed to pack this function in an PHP evaluable payload (evalueate it as a string in another PHP file may be on another server).

```
$abc = "testABC";
$xyz = new TestClass();
$test = true;
$x = function () use ($test, $xyz, $abc) {
    echo $abc;
    var_dump($test, $xyz);
};
```

This function will be packed into a string like this:

```
$payload = function () {
    $test = unserialize('b:1;');
    $xyz = unserialize('O:9:"TestClass":0:{}');
    $abc = unserialize('s:7:"testABC";');
    echo $abc;
    var_dump($test, $xyz);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this done, I wrote following function which pulls out the functions code, matches any `use(...)` clauses and renames the variable it is called. In the end, it'll assign the `use(...)` variables as a unserializeable string.

```
function packAnonFunction($payload, ...$args) {
    $func = new ReflectionFunction($payload);
    $filename = $func->getFileName();
    $start_line = $func->getStartLine() - 1;
    $end_line = $func->getEndLine();
    $length = $end_line - $start_line;

    $source = file($filename);
    $body = implode("", array_slice($source, $start_line, $length));
    $body = preg_replace('/(\$[a-z]+)\ \=\ function/', '\\$payload = function', $body);
    if(preg_match('/use\s\((\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,\s\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\)/', $body, $matches)) {
        $vars = $matches[1];
        if(strpos($vars, ', ') !== false) {
            $parts = explode(', ', $vars);
        } else {
            $parts = [$vars];
        }
        $return = [];
        foreach($parts as $key => $variable) {
            $return[$variable] = $args[$key];
        }
        $variableString = "";
        foreach($return as $var => $value) {
            $value = serialize($value);
            $variableString .= "\t{$var} = unserialize('{$value}');\n";
        }

        $body = str_replace(" use (" . $vars . ")", "", $body);
        $body = str_replace("{\n", "{\n" . $variableString, $body);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

You could just use it like this:

```
$abc = "testABC";
$xyz = new TestClass();
$test = true;
$x = function () use ($test, $xyz, $abc) {
    echo $abc;
    var_dump($test, $xyz);
};

echo packAnonFunction($x, $test, $xyz, $abc);
```

The only lag I wasn't to get around is, that you'll have to put the args (`$test, $xyz, $abc`) in the same order as you assigned the `use(...)` statement.

See it in operation: https://3v4l.org/89pXm

So what do you think about it?